# Issue building Apache Spark with Avro

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, spark-avro

I am trying to build spark from [master](https://github.com/apache/spark) branch with `./build/sbt clean package`

I want to test something specific to spark-avro submodule. However when I run the `./bin/spark-shell` and try:

`scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._`

I receive ***object avro is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql***

Am I missing a build parameter to test spark-avro? I could not find much from in the docs.

```
test@tests/spark$ ./bin/spark-shell
NOTE: SPARK_PREPEND_CLASSES is set, placing locally compiled Spark classes ahead of assembly.
20/02/21 14:28:52 WARN Utils: Your hostname, pascals resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.11 instead (on interface enp0s31f6)
20/02/21 14:28:52 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/02/21 14:28:52 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.0.11:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1582291738090).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_242)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters
<console>:23: error: object avro is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
       import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT` is the way to go, as documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html)

Comment: Do you need to build master? The latest releases would work the same way

Comment: I was trying to build master. I did not pay attention to the documentation related to building external packages with spark.